# How do I call up the iPhone keyboard in Titanium?

Tags: iphone, titanium

I'd like to show the keyboard and get user input without a text field. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Titanium personally so I don't know if this is possible, but usually this is done with a hidden textfield and listening to events on that field.

Comment: Downvoted, really? This is something how you would go about doing it using native objective-c code. Figure out how to create the equivalent using Titanium. Just because something doesn't give you the exact code how to do something does not mean it's not still useful.

Comment: Wasn't myself that downvoted your answer. Since no one else has anything else to contribute I guess I'll be using hidden fields.